# Get CSS value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using JQuery to try and get the value of the `top` from css.

However, where I have read a lot of things saying `$('modal').css('top')` will return a string "40" it is in fact retruning "40px".

Is there any way I can get this into an integer format. The component is not yet rendered on the page, I am trying to find the default position so I can set it using JS. This means that position().Top = 0 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
parseInt($('.modal').css('top'), 10);
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5w7p1pr/1/)

So it will not consider px or anything

I hope model is class or id , not Blank

Comment: Is it ever possible that `top` value will be returned anything other than decimal?

Comment: I tried this and it returned "NaN". Modal is an element passed into the funtion so ti is always pointing at the correct element.

Comment: Issue was I'd copied your code and forgot to remove the '' from the modal bit and mine is a declared variable. Stupidity. This is the solution I'll use because its a bit neater. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$.fn.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to do that...

```
$('modal').position().top
```

If that doesn't work in your situation, you could use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`, because some browsers *will* give you fractional portions of pixels in some situations.

Comment: The component is a popup though which is yet to be rendered, so this is returning 0.

Comment: @alex Please do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/Yl5qIi

Answer (score 0):

One solution involves regex replacement and cast to Number:

```
var topInt = Number($('modal').css('top').replace(/px$/,''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6n8xu0gf/1/

Comment: You are passing a string to `replace()`, not a regex, so the `$` would be treated literally.